# How to find pending timers in Linux kernel

Tags: timer, linux-kernel, kernel

I am developing a driver in Linux kernel. I have a timer that periodically does some stuff. For example, every 40ms, the timer will be expired. But, when I look at the remaining time called by some arm function to retrieve time, the remaining time is not 40ms, but less than 1ms, e.g. 960us. I think this remaining time must be caused by some other timer tick which is every 1ms. How can I find pending timers in my kernel? I have tried timer_pending(), but I need to first know the name of the timer first.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Other timers will not affect your timer. Why do you think this would be a problem?

Comment: That's true. But, it looks like there is a timer tick that affects my programming the ARM timer. Although I call tick_nohz_idle_enter(), it still has another timer that always says I need to stop at the time before 40ms.

Answer (score 0):

All timers are listed in `/proc/timer_list`.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I find pending timer in kernel? I mean not from the sysfs. More importantly, how do I disable any pending timers given I do not know their names?

Comment: If you disable that other timer, the code that installed that timer will break. You have to find out *why* that other timer was installed to prevent this, and this is not possible without the information in `timer_list`.

Comment: only HRES timers are listed in /proc/timer_list,  low resolution timer lists are not listed